# Increase memory in SpringToolSuite v4.0.1

Tags: spring-tools-4

I'm unable to increase the memory for the app, and app keeps its default 1Gb of heap.
Seems the settings in SpringToolSuite4.ini (what used to be STS.ini) are being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the "-Xmx" configuration BEFORE the "-startup" seems to resolve the problem.